# How can I add a reminder from a template to an event?

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders, templates

In an existing event, if I click on "Reminders" to add one, I only get the option to create a new reminder, but I find no way to use an already existing reminder template.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. There are no reminder templates, just message templates you can reuse inside the reminder.

Comment: So the "Save as template" checkbox that you get when creating a reminder actually only means "Create message template"? That's a shame...

Comment: Right it's just the message template.